# I am stuck getting a JSON return from the Linkedin API

Tags: javascript, json, api, linkedin-api

I am using the RESTFUL API request. Here is my code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var LinkedinAuth = "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=75rsv9vpa1ixv3&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmattobra.github.io/page.html&state=987654321&scope=r_basicprofile"
   $(button).click(function(){
     LinkedinAuth
    }) 
   var start = function(){$.getJSON("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,skills,educations,languages,twitter-accounts)?format=json", function(data){console.log(data)})
 }
```

I have the user log in. And then it brings them to the next page. however, the json never gets returned.

Comment: You aren't doing anything to authenticate anybody on click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see you calling the start() function anywhere in your code. You only declare it. I think you should put it inside the button click function.

Comment: i called it but it did not return the json. does the console.log only print out the json within the request?

Comment: The console.log(data) will only print out the data that were included as a response returned by the web service. What did you expect it to print out?